# Shell script to sum columns associated with a name

Tags: bash, shell, sum, ksh

I have a file with thousands of numbers on column 1 and each sequence of these numbers are associated with a single person. Would someone have any idea on how can I create a shell script to sum column 1 for that specific person, eg:

```
John is 10+20+30+50 = 110
```

Output of the script would be: `John 110` and so on and so forth..

I have tried with while, for, etc but I can't associate the sum to the person :(

Example of the file:

```
10 John
20 John
30 John
50 John
10 Paul
10 Paul
20 Paul
20 Paul
20 Robert
30 Robert
30 Robert 
60 Robert 
80 Robert
40 Robert
40 Robert
40 Robert
15 Mike
30 Mike
```

Comment: please update the question with your additional requirements (eg, average) and the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{ map[$2]+=$1 } END { for (i in map) { print i" "map[i] } }' file
```

Using awk, create an array with the name as the first index and a running total of the values for each name. At the end, print the names and totals.

Answer (score 1):

One `awk` solution that prints averages to 2 decimal places and orders output by name:

```
awk '
    { total[$2]+=$1
      count[$2]++
    }
END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
      for ( i in total )
          printf "%-10s %5d / %-5d = %5.2f\n", i, total[i], count[i], total[i]/count[i]
    }
' numbers.dat
```

This generates:

```
John         110 / 4     = 27.50
Mike          45 / 2     = 22.50
Paul          60 / 4     = 15.00
Robert       340 / 8     = 42.50
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Raman, it worked... do you happen to know if would possible to perform a calculation on the same awk to get the average of each one? For example, John is 10+20+30+50 = 110, 110 / 4 = 27

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- data resides in a file named `numbers.dat`
- we'll store totals and counts in arrays but calculate averages simply for display (OP can decide if averages should also be stored in an array)

One `bash` solution using a couple associative arrays to keep track of our numbers:

```
unset      total count
declare -A total count

while read -r number name
do
    (( total[${name}] += $number))
    (( count[${name}] ++ ))
done < numbers.dat

typeset -p total count
```

This generates:

```
declare -A total=([Mike]="45" [Robert]="340" [John]="110" [Paul]="60" )
declare -A count=([Mike]="2" [Robert]="8" [John]="4" [Paul]="4" )
```

If we want integer based averages (ie, no decimal places):

```
for i in ${!total[@]}
do
   printf "%-10s %5d / %-5d = %5d\n" "${i}" "${total[${i}]}" "${count[${i}]}" $(( ${total[${i}]} / ${count[${i}]} ))
done
```

This generates:

```
Mike          45 / 2     =    22
Robert       340 / 8     =    42
John         110 / 4     =    27
Paul          60 / 4     =    15
```

If we want the averages to include, say, 2 decimal places:

```
for i in ${!total[@]}
do
   printf "%-10s %5d / %-5d = %5.2f\n" "${i}" "${total[${i}]}" "${count[${i}]}" $( bc <<< "scale=2;${total[${i}]} / ${count[${i}]}" )
done
```

This generates:

```
Mike          45 / 2     = 22.50
Robert       340 / 8     = 42.50
John         110 / 4     = 27.50
Paul          60 / 4     = 15.00
```

Output sorted by name:

```
for i in ${!total[@]}
do
   printf "%-10s %5d / %-5d = %5.2f\n" "${i}" "${total[${i}]}" "${count[${i}]}" $( bc <<< "scale=2;${total[${i}]} / ${count[${i}]}" )
done | sort
```

This generates:

```
John         110 / 4     = 27.50
Mike          45 / 2     = 22.50
Paul          60 / 4     = 15.00
Robert       340 / 8     = 42.50
```